# Memory overflow in Javascript with "+="

Tags: javascript

I need to concat hundreds of Javascript strings like this:

```
var result = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 300; i ++ ) {
    result += DATA[i] + 'Some Dynamic Text';
}
```

The `DATA[i]` is **pretty large** (Like 300KB or more, it's image's base64 represents).

When I execute this code, the browser pops up an memory overflow error.(The break point is `result += DATA[i]`)

How can I optimize this code to avoid this kind of memory issue ?

==== EDIT ====
I didn't make it clear before, so you can consider the `DATA[i]` is pretty large and I can't change it. Every concat is also append some dynamic text.

Comment: `DATA.join("");` will work.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/SDtjW/ It sounds strange that that amount of data would cause memory errors. Can you show an example that throws the error?

Comment: Can you show us a demo of your issue?

Comment: This might help you https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-javascript

Comment: At first the data was "about 100 characters" and now it's "pretty large". So how large, in characters, is the array and the resulting string in total?

Comment: @Juhana, Sorry I didn't make it clear, I just update my question.

Comment: would it be possible to store the result in an array ? it would allow you more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug using a [`try {} catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch):

```
var result = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 300; i ++ ) {
    try {
      result += DATA[i];
    }
    catch ( e ) {
        console.log('An error occured on DATA[' + i + ']');
        console.log('Value:' + DATA[i]);
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

---

Why would you store an image in base64 and send it to the front end, because you want to store it offline? Isn't that that cache control is for?

Without any more information i cannot suggest you to use that approach :(

But rater look into how to set a long lasting cache on the image itself.

---

Btw, you can use [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) if `DATA` is a native array:

```
var result = DATA.join('');
```

If `DATA` is an array like object (`arguments`, `{'0': 1, '1': 2, length: 2}`) you can use:

```
var result = [].join.call(DATA, '');
```

This want solve your memory overflow, but will be faster.

Comment: You missed a zero, 300kB ~= 300 * 1000

Comment: @Gareth OP started stating that each element in the array? is 100 chars long

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't realise that the question had changed there.

Answer (score 0):

Please look here .. This should help you

[Javascript and VERY LONG string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637586/javascript-and-very-long-string)

Also please look at Javascript StringBuilder at -

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12375/JavaScript-StringBuilder

Answer (score -1):

What if you use

```
result = DATA.join("");
```

Comment: Obviously this won't work since the same amount of memory is required for the operation.

Comment: @Joren: Thing is, though...it's not.  With the loop, each concat creates another string. If we go with the OP's numbers, 300KB * 300 == 90MB total; building `result` by catting creates ~150x that (over 13GB!) in garbage over the course of 300 concats.   Depending on how the implementation's GC works (which ECMA doesn't specify), that garbage might stick around til the browser gets control back.  `.join()`, on the other hand -- particularly since it's typically implemented in native code -- almost certainly knows how to create a string without  hundreds of intermediate objects.