# Adding Html using innerHTML property doesn't fire jQuery ready event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having some performance issues using `.html()` method of jQuery because it was being really slow. So I searched for alternatives and I found some:

- [jQuery html() acting really slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1063303/1204249)
- http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-than-innerhtml

So I am now replacing the `.html()` by the method suggested. But now I have another problem:

Javascript that is inside the Html to be added is not being executed.

I have written a simple fiddle to show what is happening:

- [Javascript not being executed](https://jsfiddle.net/bbsLy56d/1/)

Can anyone suggest how could I solve this because I need the javascript to be executed.

Comment: Check this out ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml

Comment: Yes, in the by babyblade567 mentioned question have a look at the answer with stripandexcute function. This is working for me. See this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/bbsLy56d/3/). I only had to change `innerText` to `innerHTML` in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to `eval()` the script:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container"),
    content = document.getElementById("content");

$("#button2").on("click", function(){
    container.innerHTML = content.innerHTML;
    var scripts = container.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for(var i=0, l=scripts.length; i<l; i++) eval(scripts[i].innerText);
});
```

### JS Fiddle Demo

Answer (score 0):

For me the first button fires the script, the second doesn't.

That is because .innerHTML only refers to text within an element, not scipts or other tags.